# Git: index file open failed: Permission denied on "git status". Hosted on Bitbucket

Tags: linux, git, bitbucket

I've been having this issue for the last couple of days when trying to make, either, a git status or git pull. The repository is hosted on Bitbucket.

Tried several things to make this work (there are some posts related to this on stackoverflow, but they didn't work).

Here is the issue:

```
user@Host:/repo/$ git status
fatal: index file open failed: Permission denied
fatal: git status --porcelain failed
```

If I do a "git pull":

```
user@Host:/repo/$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 77, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (30/30), done.
remote: Total 56 (delta 37), reused 41 (delta 22)
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects

fatal: failed to write object
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

I double checked the local permissions and everything seems to be fine. I have permission to all the files.

**Note:**

If I use "sudo" everything seem to work as regular, however I don't have any SSH credentials for root on that deployment machine. It makes me think it is an issue with permissions (as the error explains), however: what it could be, if I'm the owner of all the files, including the files inside .git/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did you get the files from the remote?

Comment: did you `clone` the remote?

Comment: yes, I did a clone to the remote server over SSH

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Got the same error `fatal: index file open failed: Permission denied` by run `git status`, and I checked `.git/index` by

```
$ ls -al .git/index
```

to my surprise, it's

```
----------  1 Kjuly  staff  768248 Sep  2 11:07 .git/index
```

I've no idea why & how it changed. Anyway, after I changed it's permission back to `644` by

```
$ chmod 644 .git/index
```

`git status` works.

Comment: Any concern with this file having 644? Looks like it defaults to nothing for others. I went ahead and chown'd my files to the desired user.

Comment: @Bix It should be ok & enough for current user in your system. 644 will make current user able to read & write (but can't execute), for group & other users in your system, they're read only. Further reading about file permission, you can search w/ the keyword `terminal chmod`. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 8):

Make sure the .git directory and its files/subdirectories are owned and writable by your user. This sounds like the repository was either cloned under a different user account or as root user (e.g. through `sudo`).

It does not matter where the remote of the repository is hosted, git status only accesses the local repository.

Comment: yes, that's correct. change the owner of the parent directory of `.git` everything working just fine combined with the answer from @Kjuly

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and was wondering what could be the cause .. looked around and thought what I was doing and what was touching the file system and the working directory - and I had a suspicion that the files were opened by an IDE with some locks, when I performed the merge and changed branches in a terminal git. Closed the IDE, closed the shell, git pull went OK, no error messages. I had no user changes in the system, so I think a file lock or something the IDE was doing "for me" with the git repo behind the scenes were the reason. Hope this helps someone somewhat. If you are experiencing the same issue and want to get to the bottom of it (not just fix it) ask yourself "Who/what can possibly be touching and changing file ownership of my .git and working directory" ? In my case the suspect was Microsoft Visual Studio. I think the remote repo type investigations and operations are just red herrings and wound dressings (or nuclear options) that do not get to the crux of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem with BitBucket today. Here is the workaround that worked for me:

```
git remote set-url origin https://_username_@bitbucket.org/_my_/_repo_.git
git pull
git push
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:_my_/_repo_.git
```